# How to design a page that supports Android N(Nougat) API 24(Multi Window design)?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I have some doubts regarding creating perfect design that supports Multi Window feature(from API 24). Please find below for some of my doubts.

1. Width and Height of a page till Marshmallow(API 23) is fixed size,
       from Nougat(API 24) width and height of application will change
       based on full screen mode, split-screen mode and free-form mode. How to handle these
       kind of width and height related issues?
2. If in normal mode for example 4 big images are filling my complete
   width of the device, if we change it to multi window mode then width
   gets reduced means then those 4 images will not fit in the UI. How
   to handle these kind of situations?
3. Do we need to take care of text sizes and other attributes for both
   normal and multi window mode? If yes how to do that?
4. Any other thing we need to keep in mind when designing a layout that
   support API 24?

Answer (score 0):

Now your screens should be adapted for different screen sizes. You can process this by obtaining screen width and height in runtime and fit your design dynamically. It is a long way but if you want a perfect-fit design, I think it's the most appropriate approach.

If you don't need such a flexible screen, you can set android:minimalHeight and/or android:minimalWidth and be sure that all major UI elements are always visible.

If you don't want to be so strict you can use ScrollView not to depend on height of the screen and android:layout_width="match_parent" to be independent of screen width. Actually, in this case, you should test your app on various devices to make sure that all app sections are displayed correctly.

Several other things which you need to care about you can find in article http://blog.azoft.com/android-7-0-nougat-features-for-business-apps/.